# Why cannot convert input value to number type in Windows 8 Phone app emulator?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am very new to Windows Phone development. Now I am doing my very first tutorial. The problem is I cannot type cast the input value of Windows Phone emulator to number. My code is as follows:

My code in button click event:

```
int first_num = Convert.ToInt32(firstNumTxt.Text);
int sec_num = Convert.ToInt32(secNumTxt.Text);
if(first_num==sec_num)
{
     resultLabel.Text = "Numbers are equal";
}
else
{
     resultLabel.Text = "Numbers are not equal";
}
```

I am experienced in ASP.NET C# Web development. Whenever I type cast like this, it is throwing type casting exception. How can I convert that to integer?

Comment: You haven't even shown the value that you are trying to parse, so how could we help?

Comment: Put breakpoints on line 1 and 2, see what the value is of the `.Text` properties, that should point you in the right direction

Comment: for text box 1 , I typed 3 and for 2, I typed 9 . No white spacing .

Comment: Try using `int.TryParse(...)` instead of a direct `Convert`, as you will then be able to detect when the type conversion failed.

Comment: *I am experienced in ASP.NET C# Web development* but you didn't debug this?

Comment: Please post the _exact_ exception message.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `int.TryParse(...)` instead of `Convert`, as this will allow you to detect when the conversion fails.

The following example shows you how this could work:

```
int first_num;
int sec_num;

if (int.TryParse(firstNumTxt.Text, out first_num))
{
    if (int.TryParse(secNumTxt.Text, out sec_num))
    {
        if(first_num==sec_num)
        {
             resultLabel.Text = "Numbers are equal";
        }
        else
        {
             resultLabel.Text = "Numbers are not equal";
        }
    }
    else
        resultLabel.Text = "Second number not valid";
}
else
    resultLabel.Text = "First number not valid";
```